# Nested DO loops in OPEN MP

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am trying to understand nested DO loops in OPENMP. There are many forums regarding this, but I did not find an answer for the following question.

Let us consider two scenarios. The question will be below the codes

Case a)

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO
      DO i = 1,N
        DO j = 1,M
          ...code...
         END DO
       END DO
```

Case b)

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO
      DO i = 1,N
      !$OMP PARALLEL DO
         DO j = 1,M
            ... code ...
          END DO
      END DO
```

`Question`. I am not sure whether the following statements are correct

1. In case (a) the first loop will be shared by the threads, like say Thread 1 having **i** between say 1 and 10, thread 2 having **i** between 11 and 20 and so on and so forth. But here each thread will have **j** values between 1 and M, isn't it or will the second loop will also be forked between all threads like the first one?
2. In case (b) thread 1 can have values of **i** between 1 and 10 and **j** between say 10 and 20 (and not the entire range).

Is this how the pattern works? I am sorry if I have failed to express my thoughts and the question is unclear.

Comment: How exactly is this a C++ question?

Comment: In the first case there will be `N` threads. The first one has `i == 1`, the second one – `i == 2`, etc. And each of them will perform an inner loop, where `j` will change from 1 to `M`. I'm not sure about the second one though, that's why I post it as a comment.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I thought the only difference is #pragma instead of !$OMP DO and for loop instead of DO loop. I was more interested in the concept. If you feel like it does not fit in the purview of C++ , I shall delete it

Comment: @FreeNickname Yes. That was what was confusing me. When I read documentation on OPENMP, people use the second one as well, but I am not sure as to what the context is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second version makes difference only when [nested parallelism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5270/aewbc/index.html) in OpenMP is enabled. If yes, then it makes another level dividing of threads. If it is not enabled, it is ignored.

You cannot say how the threads exactly divide the indexes, because you do not specify `SCHEDULE` and the default is unspecified. But usually the default is implemented as `static` and the range of indexes is divided evenly.

The first `parallel do` divides the work among groups of threads with some values of `i` and the other one divides the values of `j` to individual threads inside these groups.

Comment: Yes. This is precisely the thing I wanted to know. Thanks. So in first case each thread will loop through the entire j range, where as in the second case, if nested omp is implemented, then the second loop will also be forked. Thanks alot :)

Comment: collapse(2) in the first !$OMP instruction is better than nested omp do loops